# TypeScript Dictionary with restricted keys

Tags: typescript, dictionary

Using TypeScript, I want to create a Dictionary type mapping a string to an object.
I want the value of the string to be restricted as follows.

```js
type Person = {
id: string;
name: string;
age: number;
}

type DictionaryOfPersonsNeedsFixing = {
  [idShouldBeRestrictedToMatchPersonId: string]: Person;
}
let persons: DictionaryOfPersonsNeedsFixing = {
  '1': {
    id: '1',
    name: 'John',
    age: 31
  },
  'wrongId': {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Jim',
    age: 37
  }
}
```

In the code above, I want TypeScript to tell me `wrongId` is not an allowed key and that we can only use '2' as the key.

Or another way would be, TypeScript should tell me `id: '2'` is not allowed, and that `id` should be set to `wrongId`.

I have tried updating the `Person` type to restrict `id` as follows:

```js
type Person<K = string> = {
  id: K;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

Now, I can create a Person whose `id` must be `'2'`, using the following syntax:

```js
let jim: Person<'2'> = {
  id: '2',
  name: 'Jim'
  age: 37
}
```

Here, I'll get an error, if I try to set the `id` field to anything other than `'2'`.

Similarly, I am able to update the `Dictionary` object to restrict the set of keys to a predefined set as follows:

```js
type DictionaryOfPersonsWithRestrictedIds = {
  [id in '1' | '2' | '3']?: Person<id>;
}
```

With this, TypeScript tells me there is an error if `Person.id` does not match the dictionary key. E.g.

```js
let personsWithIncorrectKey: DictionaryOfPersonsWithRestrictedIds = {
  '1': {
    id: '1',
    name: 'John',
    age: 31
  },
  'wrongId': { // I get a red squiggle for this whole object since wrongId is not an allowed key
    id: '2',
    name: 'Jim',
    age: 37
  }
}

let personsWithIncorrectKey: DictionaryOfPersonsWithRestrictedIds = {
  '1': {
    id: '1',
    name: 'John',
    age: 31
  },
  '2': {
    id: '3', // I get a red squiggle under id, since '2' is expected.
    name: 'Jim',
    age: 37
  }
}
```

I want to be able to do this for any `id`, not just a predefined list.

I want the Dictionary key to match (i.e. be consistent with) the `Person` `id` field for any possible `id`.

Is this possible using TypeScript Types/Interfaces without having to write my own validation functions?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOwDwGkoQB7AlQBNEpFh4BLVAcwD4oBeKAbwFgAoKbqSogLiiYA3Jx5RUAQwC2EQeSq1RXHpJpyJAV2kAjBMoC+nTqEhQAIpQDGwLDnyESZCtXpNWYngG0YvVEIBdAH5BOCQ0dBg6Q2MOKzRyKCJrYHc7PAJiUgVXOgAKAQsUrDoASiYGImVOABsIVJ1JIndkmzz2FW4AcgBGLsEO8XE+QV6ugBpPIYkZDS6AKWQAC1QJqaG1DQBmHvWDSc6oLoB3eDQaAEkifo9D4cKugCY1u54pWVH5ymkX6e5NwRbADse04BlKwiAA) work for you?  If so I'll write up an anwer

Comment: @jcalz yes, it does!